# Cannot boot from MacOS or Windows after attempting to shrink Boot Camp partition on MacBook

Tags: macos, boot, partitioning, boot-camp

**What I was doing:**
I wanted to free up some space from my Boot Camp/Win 10 partition so I could install Linux. I used AOMEI's partition tools on Windows to shrink my Windows partition by 100gb. In the middle of the partitioning after my laptop restarted (60-70% done), my MacBook unexpectedly rebooted.

After it rebooted I got a Windows blue screen, with the error "Bad_System_Config_Info, and then restarted itself afterwards. After starting up all I saw is a blinking gray file icon with a question mark, and I rebooted my laptop again, this time holding down alt/option, and was greeted with no bootable drives to choose from. I entered the Mac Internet Recovery.

**My current problem:**
Inside the recovery settings, I opened up Disk Utility. There was no Mac OS partition, only a 250gb Windows one (500gb laptop). Despite the Windows partition only being 250gb, it says all 500gb was used up. 
[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]
I have no idea what to do now, and I have some fairly important stuff on my Windows drive.

Comment: As with all partitioning tools, they warn you to backup your data before performing these types of procedures. AOMEI says “We suggest you backup your important data before moving or resizing your partition.”

Answer (score 1):

**Golden Rule:** Never attempt to modify the partition structure on a Boot Camp machine from inside Windows.
Windows simply doesn't understand how it is being 'fooled' into thinking it's in charge.

There are two companies who make software that is capable of adjusting the partitioning without having to completely remove then re-install the Boot Camp structure to resize it.

Neither of those is Apple.

Paragon make [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/)  &  [CampTune](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/camptune/)
TwoCanoes make [WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/)

Unfortunately, as you already broke it, only Paragon HDM & WinClone used together ***might*** be able to rescue it. Each has a different set of tools & capabilities I've used in the past to recover a drive wrecked in a similar manner.

Unfortunately, to even get that far, you need to be able to get into macOS.  Your best bet is going to be to attempt the rescue from another Mac, either by physically removing the drive if possible, or by starting up in [Target Disk mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462).

Alternatively, you could attempt [something like this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/196733/85275) or [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/282550/85275)
[klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) is one of the only people I know who can pretty much knit you a new hard drive if you give him the wool. I think, though, that he has tired of spending entire days over TeamViewer fixing these messes for people; he hasn't been so active in recent months.

The third alternative, as mentioned in comments -  & by far the simplest & cheapest - is to just reformat the whole lot & recover from your backup.